# How to Split string into an array using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When Domain Model property `Name` gets data from the database it's a string `"David,James"`, but I have created another View Model to convert that string into an array `["David","James"]`. I have used my ViewModel in the read method now, now the ViewModel should read the Name property as `["David","James"]`. I am not sure how to make it happen.
I would appreciate if anybody has any suggestion on how to make it happen.

**Domain Model:**

```cs
public class FullName
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Address {get; set;} 
}
```

**View Model:**

```cs
public class NameViewModel
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Name { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set;} 
}
```

Read Method:

```cs
public ActionResult Name_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    try
    {             
        DataSourceResult result = Identity.ToDataSourceResult(request, NameViewModel => new
        {
            Id = NameViewModel.Id,
            Name = NameViewModel.Name ,
            Address = NameViewModel.Address,
        });

        return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: Can [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) do the work?

Comment: That was my question,sorry :)  We need to use Split method but I am not sure how to get that value from the Domain model property and assign it back to the ViewModel.

Comment: Maybe you should ask "how to get that value from the Domain model property and assign it back to the ViewModel". Talking about splitting a string will confuse a lot of people since the splitting part isn't the problem.

Comment: `viewModel.Name = domainModel.Name.Split(',');`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
    DataSourceResult result = Identity.ToDataSourceResult(request, dataModel => new NameViewModel
    {
        Id = dataModel.Id,
        Name = dataModel.Name.Split(","),
        Address = dataModel.Address,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// typical delimiter characters
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };

// verify the name exists
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    // Get the list of strings
    string[] strings = name.Split(delimiterChars);

    if (strings != null)
    {
        if (strings.Length == 1)
        {
           firstName = strings[0];
        }
        else if (strings.Length == 2)
        {
           firstName = strings[0];
           lastName = strings[1];
        }
        else if (strings.Length == 3)
        {
           firstName = strings[0];
           middleName = strings[1];
           lastName = strings[2];
        }
    }
}
```

I am not at Visual Studio, but I think that is right.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

> When Domain Model property Name gets data from the database it's a string "David,James"

That is a terrible mistake in database Design. The ideal solution would be to fix the Backend Database to actually have two fields for those distinct values.

Failing that, the next step would be to try and split on the DB side. Many modern DBMS support Views, wich can have columns computed from actuall rows. That way you could avoid issues, like different code splitting the same input differently. And you could even henceforth treat it like it was always two Columns.

If you really want or need to it in code and given this **exact** input format, [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) can deal with this. Of coruse you can get fancier, and use stuff like Regular Expressions instead. But for this example, Split seems perfectly suiteable for the case.

Comment: Those values are being added from Multiselect box.

Comment: @HelloWorld I do not see how it changes that the firstName and lastName should be seperate columns in the Database. You need one or the other so impressively often, there was never a point compressing and storing them into a single string. If you want to dispaly them as a single string for some reason, you can combine them during output: `string output = dbString[1] + "," + dbString[0];` It is always orders of magnitude easier to put something into a string, then get it back out.